# ReplaceText processor

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I have a CSV file with attribute name `EpochWithMicroSec` and value like `1512520846` and I want to append `000` at the end of value like this `1512520846000`.

I am using following configuration please help to fix this issue.
TIA

My configuration is appending 000 at the last attribute of my CSV file. How to map it to attribute `EpochWithMicroSec` attribute?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are changing the existing field value then use

**Replacement Value Strategy**

**Literal Value**

**Update Record Configs:**
[image]

Add Dynamic property

**/EpochWithMicroSec**

```
${field.value:append('000')}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only working on the attribute itself, you should use UpdateAttribute rather than ReplaceText (the latter works on the flow file contents, not attributes). In UpdateAttribute you can add a user-defined property "EpochWithMicroSec" with the same Expression you have in your ReplaceText: `${EpochWithMicroSec:append('000')}`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but its not appending the triple 000 at the end of 'EpochWithMicroSec' value. No value got appended. Can you help? @mattyb

Comment: @shrads ,That means you are **not having attribute associated with the flowfile**.. first extract the value of **EpochWithMicroSec** as attribute using Extract Text/Evaluatejson path processor then do the matt's suggestion that will work. **(or)**
if you dont want to extract the value then use **UpdateRecord** processor to change the contents of flowfile.

Comment: @Shu Thank you. Can you help me configure UpdateRecord processor configuration? –

Comment: @shrads sure, what is the format of the data? and please update the question with sample data that you are having? for reference regards to update record configs follow this link https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/189642/update-the-contents-of-flowfile-by-using-updaterec.html

Comment: @shu Please check I have updated my question with screenshots. thanks!